# remove white border from axis aligment

Tags: matplotlib

In this example

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
pyplot.pcolormesh(np.ones((212, 212)))
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

the result has an ugly white region around the matrix, because the axis are aligned to 250. Is is possible to remove this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pyplot.gca().axis('tight')
```

before the call to pyplot.show().

Comment: this is a trivial and not generic answer. I knew this, I want something more automatic, telling the axis to don't align.

Comment: It's a trivial *problem*, but perhaps you like `tight` as more generic. (Posting sample code in flat pyplot instead of the explicit object-handling suggests wanting a simple answer, to me.)